# How to find highest power of 2 less than n in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list likes

lst = [20, 40, 110]

I want to find the highest power of 2 in the list satisfied as

> For the first number, the highest power of 2 will get the first element of the list as input. So the result is 16 (closest to 20)
>
> For the next numbers, it will get the summation of previous result (i.e 16) and current number (.i.e 40) so the closest number will be 32 (closest 40 +16)

So the output what I expect is

lst_pow2 = [16, 32, 128]

This is my current code to find the highest number of a number, but for my problem it should change something because my input is list. Any suggestion? Thanks

```
# Python3 program to find highest  
# power of 2 smaller than or  
# equal to n. 
import math 
  
def highestPowerof2(n): 
  
    p = int(math.log(n, 2)); 
    return int(pow(2, p));
```

So what I tried but it does not do the summation

```
lst_power2 = [highestPowerof2(lst[i]) for i in range(len(lst))]
```

Comment: what does it do for the 3rd number? for checking 110 does it add both 16 and 32? just 32?

Comment: No. the second number only count before summation.

Comment: For the last number, it will count from the highest power 2 of second number and the number,

Comment: Just a fyi. `lst_power2 = [highestPowerof2(lst[i]) for i in range(len(lst))]` can be turned to `lst_power2 = [highestPowerof2(i) for i in lst]`. Use pythons strengths :)

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse I like your comment, but unless I'm reading it wrong, I think you should check your brackets :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perhaps use the following :

```
lst_power2 = [highestPowerof2(lst[i]+((i>0) and highestPowerof2(lst[i-1]))) for i in range(len(lst))]
```

instead of

```
lst_power2 = [highestPowerof2(lst[i]) for i in range(len(lst))]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to modify your approach thus:

1. Modify your function to take 2 integers. `prev_power` and `curr_num` (this was `n` in your code)
2. Calculate the power of 2 for the first number and add to a result list
3. Now pass this number and the next number in the list to your `highestPowerof2` function

Comment: Oooo good approach. This would make it perfect for a generator.

Answer (score 1):

Use an extra variable that keeps track of the value to be added, and build your logic while iterating.

```
lst = [20, 40, 110]

import math 

def highestPowerof2(n): 
    p = int(math.log(n, 2)) #you do not need semi colons in python
    return int(pow(2, p))

acc = 0 #to keep track of what was the last highest* power
result = []
for n in lst:
    result.append(highestPowerof2(n + acc))
    acc = result[-1]

print(result)
#Output:
[16, 32, 128]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `reduce()` too:

```
functools.reduce(lambda res,n:res+[highestPowerof2(n+res[-1])],lst,[0])[1:]
```

which is short, just the `[1:]` is ugly at the end
Or as:

```
functools.reduce(lambda res,n:res+[highestPowerof2(n+(len(res) and res[-1]))],lst,[])
```

which does not need the slicing, but it is less readable inside.

---

Full example:

```
import math,functools

def highestPowerof2(n):
    p = int(math.log(n, 2))
    return int(pow(2, p))

lst = [20, 40, 110]
print(functools.reduce(lambda res,n:res+[highestPowerof2(n+res[-1])],lst,[0])[1:])
print(functools.reduce(lambda res,n:res+[highestPowerof2(n+(len(res) and res[-1]))],lst,[]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has an accepted answer but I thought this would be a good problem that could also be solved by using a generator. The accepted answer is definitely compact but I though it would be fun to give this solution as well.

```
lst = [20, 40, 110]

import math 

def highestPowerof2(lst): 
    last = 0
    for element in lst:
      p = int(math.log(element + last, 2))
      last = int(pow(2, p)) # Remember the last value
      yield last

lst_power2 = [i for i in highestPowerof2(lst)]
print(lst_power2)
```